# mongodb aggregation on big data, how to limit push in group?

Tags: mongodb, bigdata, aggregate, push, limit

my data in collection:
any name has value for sample:

```
{
    "name" : "kamal",
    "val" : 5
}
{
    "name" : "ali",
    "val" : 3
}
{
    "name" : "mohammad",
    "val" : 12
}
{
    "name" : "kamal",
    "val" : 6
}
{
    "name" : "kamal",
    "val" : 10
}
{
    "name" : "ali",
    "val" : 11
}
{
    "name" : "mohammad",
    "val" : 9
}
{
    "name" : "mohammad",
    "val" : 19
}
{    
    "name" : "ali",
    "val" : 6
}
```

i have 20000000 documents in my collection.
and this grow up 1000000 on day
please help me for solve this problem.
this pipeline in mongodb work:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$group:{
            _id:$name,
            vals:{$push:$val}
        }
    }
])
```

add all val for any name but in big data memory limit dont work.
**I need this:**
I need in group limit push count of data .

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$group:{
            _id:$name,
            vals:{$push:$val , $limit:500000}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Would a [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/index.html#limit-aggregation) stage before the `$group` do what you need?

Comment: How many different `name`'s do you have in this collection?  `db.test.distinct("name")`? If it's a small result, we can define `$facet` stage and limit manually per pipeline..

Comment: This restricts all documents, but I need to apply a limit to each name

Comment: About a thousand

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic solution that will make `$group` "fast" when scale goes up.

There are several approaches to handle scale:

1. Upgrade hardware, this is obviously not very effective as scale keeps growing and you'll have to keep upgrading hardware to keep up. however it is something to consider at certain times.
2. Change architecture: I'm not sure how your database is built, but under certain needs this could really speed up some queries, is your data sharded? if so is it sharded properly? there are probably many changes you can do to match your needs,  I have yet to see a perfectly setup architecture where i would say there's nothing that can be changed to improve performance.
3. The easiest of them all, use preprocessing to prepare data. Now what does this mean? it means we that we create a new collection that will be `{name: string, vals: {val: number, count: number}`, now whenever you insert or update one of your documents you'll have to update this collection as well which will create some overhead but this is the only solution that works without grand changes and is somewhat easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

**Not possible**

**Possible workaround (MongoDB >= `v3.6`):** This solution may work for you, but it has a very poor performance.

**Note:** 500.000 `val`/`name` may exceed [16MB limitation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents)

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "test",
      let: {
        username: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$username",
                "$name"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            val: 1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 500000
        }
      ],
      as: "vals"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      vals: {
        $map: {
          input: "$vals",
          in: "$$this.val"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],{allowDiskUse:true})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uaeYkY4IUEB)